# Key Value Observing in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing, key-value-coding, key-value

I've been reading up on Key Value Observing and I get that the ViewController listens to changes in the model to update the view.  Slightly differently: how does the model know that it's own parameters have been updated?

For example, I have a button on my view that changes one parameter of the model, and another button that changes another parameter.  If either one changes, I need to update the volume.  Would the best way to do this be: 1) Call the model's UpdateVolume method in each seperate "ButtonPressed" method in my ViewController OR to have the model do Key Value Observing on itself and whenever any of it parameters change, call UpdateVolume?  The later seems more convenient if I implement more parameters, each updated by the ViewController w/ a different method.

thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Having model do observation on self sounds wrong. It knows all about itself, so no need for loose coupling using KVO on itself. Just have each button call whatever public model API is needed to update the model. The model will implement whatever logic and produce a result, which will be watched by VC, using KVO, and update its views accordingly. It works like a charm.